# NodeJS: node-ffi, ref-struct, ref-array

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, ref, node-ffi

I'm writing PKCS11 cryptoki wrapper using nodejs plugins `ffi`, `ref`, `ref-struct` and `ref-array`. I have this code.

```
var hSession = this.session.handle;
var hObject = this.handle;
var $label = new (arrayType(cki.CK_UTF8CHAR))(80);

var template = new (arrayType(cki.CK_ATTRIBUTE))(1);
template[0] = new cki.CK_ATTRIBUTE({
    type:cki.CKA_LABEL, 
    pValue: $label.ref(), 
    ulValueLen: 80}) 
var res = this.cki.C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, hObject, template.ref(), 1);
if (res == cki.CKR_OK) {
    console.log("Ok");
}
else{
    console.log("Wrong "+res);
}
```

When I call this function I have wrong results (CKR_ARGUMENTS_BAD, CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID). 
Please, help me to find error.

FFI function

```
"C_GetAttributeValue":[t.CK_RV, [t.CK_SESSION_HANDLE, t.CK_OBJECT_HANDLE, t.CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR, t.CK_ULONG]],
```

Types

```js
/* CK_ATTRIBUTE is a structure that includes the type, length
 * and value of an attribute */
t.CK_ATTRIBUTE = struct({
  type: t.CK_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE,
  pValue: t.CK_VOID_PTR,

  /* ulValueLen went from CK_USHORT to CK_ULONG for v2.0 */
  ulValueLen: t.CK_ULONG  /* in bytes */
});
```

Comment: Could you try to pass a `NULL` pointer as `pValue` in the struct.  This way you can confirm, that the attribute type (and the structure as a whole) is understood correctly (giving `NULL` is used to query the actual attribute length).

Comment: Additionally you might consider using some logging pkcs#11 library to see how your function call is understood/processed. For example [this](https://github.com/jariq/pkcs11-logger) -- the first one I googled, didn't test (can't help here as I have some proprietary logging library which I cannot share)

Comment: Do you have any progress (I am just curious and saw your new question)?

Comment: When I set `pValue=null` it works OK, but I can't receive value from `pValue`

Comment: I found some iteresting links. Its can be helpful. C++ sample of function [link](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__11__7__OBJECT__MANAGEMENT__FUNCTIONS.html). `ref` description [link](http://tootallnate.github.io/ref/#exports-NULL_POINTER). I receive `ukValueLen`, but I can't set `pValue` to NULL_PTR

Comment: Does it help when you use `pValue: $label,` instead of `pValue: $label.ref(),`?

Comment: What if you change `var $label = new (arrayType(cki.CK_UTF8CHAR))(80);` into `var $label = new Buffer(80);` and use it as `pValue: $label,`?

Comment: Thank you. It seems working. But now I need slice `Buffer`, because `ulValueLen=18`

Comment: `$label.toString('ascii',0,18)`?

Comment: Just looked up the encoding of `CKA_VALUE` in PKCS#11 and it should be UTF-8 (RFC2279) -> the correct way is probably `$label.toString('utf8',0,18)`

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you vary mutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Transcript of discussion in comments)

Use pure `Buffer` to provide the buffer to store the attribute value:

```
var $label = new Buffer(80);
```

Pass it in the structure as follows:

```
template[0] = new cki.CK_ATTRIBUTE({
    type:cki.CKA_LABEL, 
    pValue: $label, 
    ulValueLen: $label.length})
```

Then use `$label.toString('utf8',0,<ulValueLen>)` to get the actual string.

Note: I am not proficient with Node FFI, but this approach *just seem to work*.

Comment: To convert `Buffer` for attribute `CKA_CLASS` use `$label.readInt32LE()`